# Comparison of two vectors leads to an exception

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, segmentation-fault, fstream

Comparing the two vectors in the if statement throws an exception (segmentation fault).
I was having an attempt to create a system, which, user details are being saved in a file and being read to give security questions to the user.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <vector>
    #include <fstream>

        int main(int argc, char** argv) {    
                std::vector<std::string>setup_file_contents_vec{};
                std::ifstream setup_file_required_scan( "exposcan.txt" );    
                std::string buffer;
                while(setup_file_required_scan >> buffer) { setup_file_contents_vec.push_back(buffer); }
                std::vector <std::string> user_details_confirmation(3);
                std::cout << " Login details 1/3\n\n";
                std::cout << "First Name : ";
                std::cin >> user_details_confirmation[0];
                if(user_details_confirmation[0] != setup_file_contents_vec[0]) {/* code */} /*Exception occurs*/
    }
```

Comment: Even when adding a `main` function in an attempt to make it a somewhat working [mre], it will still not replicate the problem you ask about. The code should simply not build. There should not be any "input" operator `>>` when you do `std::cin >> user_details_confirmation[0]`. Please create a proper [mre] which replicates the problem you ask about, and doesn't have other errors. IO fact, copy-paste the actual code you have, if it's minimal enough.

Comment: On an unrelated note, instead of e.g. `for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++){ std::cout << " "; }` why not simply `std::cout << "      ";`?

Comment: Does adding `#include <string>` help? Since you are using `std::string`, you should include the header that defines it.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I already have it it's just I forgot to include it in this question.

Comment: One possibility: the file `exposcan.txt` is empty or doesn't exist in the current working directory, so `setup_file_contents_vec` is empty, and then `setup_file_contents_vec[0]` exhibits undefined behavior.

Comment: Maybe I should have started like this, but please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: You don't check if `setup_file_required_scan` opened correctly or not.

Comment: Also take this as an opportunity to learn two things: First that you must *always* check for success; And secondly how to *debug* your programs. For example using a *debugger* to catch crashes as and when they happen and then located where they happen in your code and how to examine variables and their values at the time of the crash.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Yes that was the issue, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @IgorTandetnik the issue was that the file was empty.